# SQL CASE: IF 2 different columns = something then the 3rd column = something; IF [a] = a AND [b] = b THEN [c] =c

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

The following is my script:

```
SELECT 
    *
    ,CASE WHEN (Confirmed = 'YES' AND R.Performed IS NULL AND (R.Name NOT LIKE 'C%' OR R.Name NOT LIKE 'Q%')) 
          THEN s.Description = 'CONFIRMED' 
     END
FROM
    Repair r
INNER JOIN 
    Conversion C
ON 
    R.Confirmed = C.confirmed
AND 
    r.performed = c.performed
INNER JOIN
    Status s
ON 
    a.name = s.name
WHERE 
    Status = 'CONFIRMED'
AND 
    Received BETWEEN '01-31-2013' AND '12-31-2013'
and part = '4'
```

NOTE:  I GET RED SQUIGGLIES UNDER THE LAST `'='` AND `'END'` IN THE CASE STATEMENT.

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Why are you assigning a value to s.Description? Are you trying to do an update?

Comment: because Im writing an SSIS package and there is a lot of missing data...generally I test performed and confirmed which is a dependent for the description value.  Some performed data is missing which means the description will be null.  If the rules from my case are true then I need to make the description attribute confirmed

Comment: After the `THEN` you have to have an expression, not an assignment.

Comment: What do you propose....Im an intern

Comment: When is it possible for `(R.Name NOT LIKE 'C%' OR R.Name NOT LIKE 'Q%'))` to be false? ;-) That may help simplify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish but something like this is what you may need

```
,CASE WHEN (Confirmed = 'YES' AND R.Performed IS NULL 
           AND (R.Name NOT LIKE 'C%' OR R.Name NOT LIKE 'Q%')) 
 THEN 'CONFIRMED' ELSE s.Description END AS Description
```

if you just wanted to change the value of Description when Confirmed = 'YES' then the following would work

```
,CASE WHEN Confirmed = 'YES' THEN 'CONFIRMED' ELSE s.Description END AS Description
```

You would also need to not use `SELECT *`, and have each column identified separately so `Description` doesn't appear twice in the select. I'm not sure why `s.Description IS NULL AND ...` is not part of your CASE condition, if you're trying to fill in missing Descriptions.

Comment: This still doesn't work.  I need the s.Description column to = 'CONFIRMED' when the other columns are true.

Comment: Can you add some more content to your question describing exactly when Description should be "CONFIRMED", and when it should keep its existing value. I simply copied the condition from your question, so I assumed that was what you wanted.

Comment: Just for simplicity...`WHEN [Confirmed] = 'YES' THEN [s.Description] ='CONFIRMED'`

Comment: And when Confirmed does not equal 'YES' then Description should keep it's value? What about those other pieces you have in your CASE condition?

Comment: The other pieces don't really matter.  is the syntax of what I want to do that matters...im probably better of making manual changes in the db

Comment: I would be very wary about taking that avenue. The syntax of doing it in the select is very simple, as I've shown above. Who knows what the ramifications are for permanently altering the actual data.

Comment: The change needs to be made anyways.  im writing a big ssis package and find myself doing more cleanup than anything.  Conversion is pretty much a 'rules' base and is missing some rules.  The case statement is simply a rule that is missing...thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` statement should look like below. You are getting error cause you are trying to add value to `description` column `s.Description = 'CONFIRMED'` which is not allowed.

```
CASE WHEN (Confirmed = 'YES' AND R.Performed IS NULL 
AND (R.Name NOT LIKE 'C%' OR R.Name NOT LIKE 'Q%')) 
THEN 'CONFIRMED' END AS Description
```

Comment: Im trying to make the s.Description column = 'CONFIRMED' given the other rules in the CASE statement.  This is not allowed in a query?

Comment: That's not possible cause certainly you are performing a `SELECT` and not a `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Comment: will an insert change the record permanately? that's not what I want...just for my ssis package

Comment: You are still confused, if `description` is a parameter you can still do that but it's a column in status table and you can't do that other than performing a insert/update.

Comment: Not even on a JOIN statement?

Comment: NO. Forget about JOIN ... you are doing a SELECT and that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow what you really want and its hard, but I think you want something like:

```
SELECT r.confirmed
       ,r.status
       ,a.name
       ,<other fields>
       ,CASE WHEN (    Confirmed = 'YES' 
                   AND R.Performed IS NULL 
                   AND (   R.Name NOT LIKE 'C%' 
                        OR R.Name NOT LIKE 'Q%')
                  ) 
             THEN 'CONFIRMED' 
             ELSE s.Description 
         END AS Description
FROM <your joined and filtered tables>
```

The idea is, I think, you need to alter the s.description only in the output of this select query, not in the source table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CASE s.Description WHEN (Confirmed = 'YES' AND R.Performed IS NULL AND (R.Name NOT LIKE 'C%' OR R.Name NOT LIKE 'Q%')) 
          THEN 'CONFIRMED' 
     END
```

am not using else part since you did not use that in your code and it wont cause any syntax error